# Laravel 5.4 testing route protected by $request->ajax(), how to make test ajax request?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

I am trying to test a route that does something different in the controller whether or not the request is ajax or not.

```
public function someAction(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax()){
        // do something for ajax request
        return response()->json(['message'=>'Request is ajax']);
    }else{
        // do something else for normal requests
        return response()->json(['message'=>'Not ajax']);
    }
}
```

My test:

```
    public function testAjaxRoute()
{
    $url = '/the-route-to-controller-action';
    $response = $this->json('GET', $url);
    dd($response->dump());
}
```

When I run the test and just dump the response I get back 'Not ajax' - which makes sense I guess cause *$this->json()* is just expecting back a json response, not necessarily making an ajax request. But how can I correctly test this? I have been commenting the...

```
// if($request->ajax(){
    ...need to test this code
// }else{
    // ...
// }
```

every time I need to run the test on that portion of code. I'm looking for how to make an ajax request in my test case I guess...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In Laravel 5.4 tests ***this->post()*** and ***this->get()*** methods accept headers as the third parameter.
Set **HTTP_X-Requested-With** to **XMLHttpRequest**

```
$this->post($url, $data, array('HTTP_X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest'));
```

I added two methods to **tests/TestCase.php** to make easier.

```
<?php

namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;

    /**
     * Make ajax POST request
     */
    protected function ajaxPost($uri, array $data = [])
    {
        return $this->post($uri, $data, array('HTTP_X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest'));
    }

    /**
     * Make ajax GET request
     */
    protected function ajaxGet($uri, array $data = [])
    {
        return $this->get($uri, array('HTTP_X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest'));
    }
}
```

Then from within any test, let's say **tests/Feature/HomePageTest.php**, I can just do:

```
public function testAjaxRoute()
{
  $url = '/ajax-route';
  $response = $this->ajaxGet($url)
        ->assertSuccessful()
        ->assertJson([
            'error' => FALSE,
            'message' => 'Some data'
        ]); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `$response = \Request::create($url, 'GET', ["X-Requested-With" => "XMLHttpRequest"])->json();`

Comment: This make a Request but it doesn't have the other functions for testing like, ->assertStatus(200), and ->decodeResponseJson()

Comment: You were helpful by showing that the third parameter was ["X-Requested-With" => "XMLHttpRequest"] which $this->get() and $this->post() also except and they extend from whatever classes make up all of laravels test stuff...  So, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me

```
$result = $this->actingAs($user)->json('delete', '/order/' . $order->id, ['id' => $order->id, "_method" => "DELETE"], ['X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest']);
$this->assertEquals(403, $result->response->status());
```